# How can I query multiple key criteria?

Tags: couchdb

Using couchdb, with the following json:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[ {"id":"bc26e5eae7f8c8c3486818e7e7971df0","key":{"user":"lili@abc.com","pal":["igol ≠ eagle"],"fecha":"10/5/2014"},"value":null},{"id":"cf0dc2e2874776958c59f2f544b5a750","key":{"user":"lili@abc.com","pal":["kat ≠cat"],"fecha":"10/6/2014"},"value":null},{"id":"df4ec96088ed52096db064f2ebd2310b","key":{"user":"dum@ghi.com","pal":["dok ≠ duck"],"fecha":"10/7/2014"},"value":null}]}
```

I would like to query for specific user AND specific date:

for example:
    ?user="lili@def.com"&fecha:"10/6/2014"

I also tried:
    ?user%3Dlili%40def.com%26fecha%3A10%2F6%2F2014

Needless to say, it isn't currently working as I expected (all results are shown, not only the register needed).

my view func is:

```
function(doc) {

    if (doc.USER){

        emit({user:doc.USER, pal:doc.palabras, fecha:doc.fecha});  

    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that CouchDB views are simply key/value lookups that are built at index-time, not query time. At the minute you are emitting a key with no value. If you want to look something up by two values, you'll need to emit a composite key (an array):

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.USER) {
        emit([doc.USER, doc.fecha], doc);
    }
}
```

Then you can look up matching documents by passing the array as the key:

```
?key=%5B%22lili%40def.com%22%2C%20%2210%2F6%2F2014%22%5D
```

There are optimisations you can make to this (e.g. emitting a `null` value and using `include_docs` to reduce the size of the view) but this should set you off on the right track.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still working out my mind (used to use mysql and was trying to "make couchdb" work like I was used to). Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing as `Ant P` but I tend to use strings.

```
function ( doc ) {
  if ( doc.USER ) {
    emit( 'user-' + doc.USER + '-' + doc.fecha, doc );
  }
}
```

I would also highly recommend emitting `null` instead of `doc` as a value.

Remember, you can always emit more than once depending on what kind of queries you need.

For example, if you're looking for all posts by a specific user between two dates, you could do the following view.

```
function ( doc ) {
  if ( doc.type == "post" ) {
    emit( 'user-' + doc.nombre, null );
    emit( 'fecha-' + doc.fecha, null );
  }
}
```

Then you would query the view twice `_view/posts?key="user-miUsario"`, and `_view/posts?start_key="fecha-1413040000000"&end_key="fecha-1413049452904"`. Then, once you have all of the `id`s from both views, you take the intersection and use _all_docs to get your original documents.

You end up making three requests but it saves disk space in the view, the payloads are smaller because you return `null`, and your code is simpler because you can query the same view multiple ways.

Comment: Thank you very much, valueable suggestions